# Как загрузить изображение на сайт через c# selenium chromedriver?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, chromedriver

При нажатии на button на веб-странице появляется стандартное окно загрузки файла.
Интересует самый универсальный способ, подходящий под большинство сайтов.

```
wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[.='Загрузить фото']")).Click();
new Actions(wd).SendKeys(@"C:\000.jpg").Build().Perform();
new Actions(wd).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

Пробовал так, но не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, SeleniumWebDriver не поддерживает работу с любого рода системными диалогами. Так что в любом случае нужно делать какой-то костыль для реализации этого.

Нам неизвестно что за сайт и какой костыль возможно использовать для конкретно твоего случая.

---

## 1. Если поле адреса видимое

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadhere" />
```

**Selenium Code**

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("uploadhere"));
element.SendKeys("C:\\Some_Folder\\MyFile.txt");
```

## 2. Если поле адреса НЕвидимое

```
public void AttachFile(WebDriver driver, By locator, String file) {
  WebElement input = driver.findElement(locator);
  Unhide(driver, input);
  input.sendKeys(file);
}

private void Unhide(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
  String script = "arguments[0].style.opacity=1;"
    + "arguments[0].style['transform']='translate(0px, 0px) scale(1)';"
    + "arguments[0].style['MozTransform']='translate(0px, 0px) scale(1)';"
    + "arguments[0].style['WebkitTransform']='translate(0px, 0px) scale(1)';"
    + "arguments[0].style['msTransform']='translate(0px, 0px) scale(1)';"
    + "arguments[0].style['OTransform']='translate(0px, 0px) scale(1)';"
    + "return true;";
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, element);
}
```

## 3. Универсальный способ

Анализ трафика и реализации POST реквеста в котором будет аплоадится картинка.

## 4. Использовать эту библиотеку:

https://github.com/ukushu/DialogCapabilities

## 5. И САМЫЙ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ДЛЯ ДАНОГО СЛУЧАЯ

> вообще забить на использование Selenium для этих задач и использьовать Instagram API.
>
> Который не так давно заимел поддержку аплоада картинок: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing

Comment: Добавил скрин окна и указал сайт к вопросу

Comment: я знаю как выглядит системная форма выбора файлов... Она для всех программ универсальная :D  нужно было скрин upload формы сайта)

Comment: Самый универсальный вариант получается - Это найти окно загрузки файлов и вставить текст именно туда? минуя OpenQA.Selenium ? Чтоб прям для всех сайтов и случаев работало

Comment: обновил ответ ...

Comment: Буду пробовать первый вариант. Т.к. нужно найти универсальное решение для всех сайтах. А не только для инсы. Трафик анализировать не вариант для меня походу.

Comment: Отпишешся сработает ли. У меня праздный интерес к этому :)

Comment: Вообще круто было бы найти расширение для Хрома, которое бы ловило такие окна в момент появления, и вставляло указанный путь. В Зеннопостер наверняка так реализовано.